# Why is userdata not working in my Terraform code?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, user-data

I am working with Terraform and trying to execute bash script using user date. Below is my code:

```
    resource "aws_instance" "web_server" {
  ami           = var.centos
  instance_type = var.instance-type
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.private.id
  private_ip    = var.web-private-ip
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  user_data = <<-EOF
          #!/bin/bash 
          yum install httpd -y
          echo "hello world" > /var/www/html/index.html
          yum update -y
          systemctl start httpd
          firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=http
          firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=https
          firewall-cmd --reload
          EOF
}
```

However, when I navigate to the public IP I do not see the "hello world" message and also do not get a response fron the server. Is there something I am missing here? I've tried going straight through the aws console and user data is unsuccesful there to.

Comment: ssh to the instannce and inspect `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

Comment: Do the commands run when you run them manually? Maybe there is an issue with your outbound connectivity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **verified** your user data on my centos instance and your script is **correct**. However, the issue is probably because of two things:

1. `subnet_id     = aws_subnet.private.id` this suggest that you've placed your instance in a private subnet. To connect to your instance form internet, it must be in **public subnet**
2. there is no `vpc_security_group_ids` specified, which leads to using a default SG from the VPC, which has internet traffic blocked by default.

Also I'm not sure what do you want to do with `private_ip    = var.web-private-ip`. Its confusing.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. It was definitely the security group and subnet. I thought that the instance would inherit the security group because it is in the same vpc, but I see know that is per instance.

Comment: user-data relies on the security_group? Why is that? It can be configured before an instance is launched, no?

Comment: @MrChadMWood I would suggest making a proper question specific to your issue.